# ffmpeg can't concat movies from two different devices

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, concatenation

I've got bunch of movies from two different Panasonic devices. As long as I concat movies from only ONE device - final movie is smooth.
However, when I add movie clip from second device, right after final movie ends playing movies from first device it display audio and only still images from movie clip from other device.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy final_movie.MP4
```

Example ffprobe:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'S6810001.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.27.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.62, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 1131 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 998 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 132 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

Second device movie clip:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'a/T00004.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.27.100
  Duration: 00:00:33.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1190 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 929 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
```

Why movie is still? How to prepare it so it could be joined correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to concat videos that likely have different profiles. Also, the audio formats are different, but they should be the same if you want to stream copy.

Use `ffprobe` to view more detailed info about each input:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_streams S6810001.MP4
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_streams a/T00004.mp4
```

In this example assuming the video in `S6810001.MP4` has Main profile and `a/T00004.mp4` has Baseline profile you can "conform" `a/T00004.mp4` to be more like `S6810001.MP4`, or vice versa (note that audio can have a profile too, so make sure you're looking at the right section in the `ffprobe` output). This example command will use the same profile and same audio format:

```
ffmpeg -i a/T00004.mp4 -profile:v main -c:a aac a/T00004_encoded.mp4
```

Now use `a/T00004_encoded.mp4` as your second input instead of `a/T00004.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy final_movie.MP4
```

Comment: Weird thing is it does play the audio from 2nd file, as per OP.